# How to create an instance if a inner class with getConstructor()

Tags: java, reflection, nosuchmethoderror, getconstructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to load a class (and its inner classes) that is already on the class path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868337/java-how-to-load-a-class-and-its-inner-classes-that-is-already-on-the-class-pa)

Could someone help me understand how to create an instance of an inner class using getConstructor.

Here is where I am at right now.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Outer{
public Outer(int i){
//things to do
}
public class Inner{
Class<?>[] type = new Class<?>[1];
Class<?> myClass;
    public Inner(int i){
    //stuff and code
    }

    public void task(){
    type[0] = Integer.class;
    try{
        myClass = Class.forName("Outer$Inner");
        Constructor construct = myClass.getConstructor(type);
        Object i = construct.newInstance(new Integer(43));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Outer outer = new Outer(new Integer(21));
Inner inner = outer.new Inner(new Integer(22));
inner.task();
}
```

}

error information

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Outer$Inner.<init>(java.lang.Integer)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
at Outer$Inner.task(Outer.java:18)
at Outer.main(Outer.java:30)
```

sorry if I am missing something obvious
If I can figure this out I would like to take input from a txt file and use the string to create objects.

Comment: This problem is not solved in the linked question.

Answer (score 6):

Does it work if you change InnerClass to be a static class instead?

It generally needs the context of the Outer class to create the inner class, if it's not a static inner class.  I believe you need to pass the Outer instance to the constructor - let me pull a random reference out my rear:

http://jroller.com/tomdz/entry/reflection_inner_classes

Comment: it sure did helped me changing an inner class to static (thanks James from 2010)

Comment: @drorsun - you're welcome

- James from 2015